# How can I add the total cost of orders in a class, from an array of that class?

Tags: javascript, html

I am try to add the total of all the items in the order Array.

The order array is dynamically updated when the form is submitted.

I am trying this by using map() to get all of the price arguments and then reduce() to get the total cost of the items.

I have tried to add it by useing the name of the waiter

```
name.addFood(foodItem);
```

But  received this message:

```
TypeError: name.addFood is not a function


<html>
        <form id="mainForm" action="#">
            <select id="menuMain" name="foodOrder">               
            </select>
            <select id="waiters" name="waiterSelection">            
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

<js>

//Waiter Constructor
class Waiter{
    constructor (name){
    this.name = name;
    this.order = [];
    this.total = 0;
    }


    //function to map() the price argument
    //and then reduce() to get the total
    addFood = function (item){
    this.order.push(item);
    this.total = this.order.map(o => o.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    }


};





//Main food array
const mainFood = [
    new Item ('Peene Primvera', 14.50),
    new Item("Lasagne", 14.50),
    new Item("Fillet Steak", 20.00)
];




//Function to submit the form 
formEl.onsubmit = function (e){

    //Selecting the choosen index from the user food and which waiter ordered 
    //it which waiter 
    const foodItem = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value;  
    const waiterName = waitersEl.options[waitersEl.selectedIndex].value;
    const waiter = waiters.find(({ name }) => name === waiterName);


    //Logic to check when submitted if both fields are true proceed 
    if (waiter && foodItem) {

        //Calling the function addFood from the Waiter
        //class to push the selection to the orders array
        //and then reduce it and put the total in the total argument
        waiter.addFood(foodItem);
        console.log(waiters);
    };




return false; // prevents redirect/refresh
```

};

This is what I get now after I submit notice the total: NAN:

```
0: Waiter
addFood: ƒ (item)
name: "Timo"
order: ["Peene Primvera (14.5)", "Peene Primvera (14.5)"]
total: NaN
```

My desired result would be:

```
0: Waiter
addFood: ƒ (item)
name: "Timo"
order: ["Peene Primvera (14.5)", "Peene Primvera (14.5)"]
total: 29
```

Comment: Just delete the "= function" after addFood, When you create a method inside a class you don't need to declare it as a function

Comment: @ tomer raitz, Thanks for the tip, but I have deleted the function and it is still throwing the ' total: NaN ' error. I can not see why the syntax seems to be good from what I see.

Comment: Is there away I can use parseInt() to convert the string